# Conveying a formula in C (% is)

Tags: c

So I have to make this formula "y = y / (3/17) - z + x / (a % 2) + PI" in C
I am having a problem with (a%2) as it is returning odd values. ie 1%2 = 0.000001

```
int assignment7()
{
#define PI 3.14
    int a=0,amod2;
    double Ny=0,y=0,z=0,x=0;
    printf("Enter values for x,y,z and a: ");
    scanf("%d%lf%lf%lf",&a,&y,&z,&x);
    //printf("%d,%lf,%lf,%lf\n",a,y,z,x);
    //amod2=1%2;
    //printf("%lf",amod2);
    Ny=y/(double)(3/17) - z+x / amod2 + PI;
    printf("%lf\n",Ny);
```

Comment: Please add your code, rather than linking to it.

Comment: Look at [**What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic**](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: That expression does not appear anywhere in your pastebin anyway.

Comment: Suggest `Ny = y/(3.0/17.0) - z + x/(a%2) + MATH_PI;` and `scanf("%lf%lf%lf%d", &y, &z, &x, &a);`

Answer (score 2):

When you say:

```
printf("%lf",amod2);
```

the compiler expects amod2 to be a "**long float**" (aka a **double**), but you defined it as:

```
int amod2;
```

Also your prompt says "x,y,z and a" but you read in the order "a,y,z,x":

```
printf("Enter values for x,y,z and a: ");
scanf("%d%lf%lf%lf",&a,&y,&z,&x);
```

that's awkward at best.

EDIT: cleaned up a bit and made some assumptions about order of operations:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    #define PI      3.14
    #define DIVSOR  (3.0/17.0)

    int assignment7 ( void );

    int assignment7 ( void ) {

            double  x       = 0.0;
            double  y       = 0.0;
            double  z       = 0.0;
            int     a       = 0;
            int     amod2;
            double  Ny;

            printf("Enter values for x,y,z and a: ");
            scanf("%lf%lf%lf%d",&x,&y,&z,&a);
            amod2 = a % 2;
            Ny = (y / DIVSOR) - z + (x / amod2) + PI;
            printf("%lf\n", Ny);
            return 0;
    }

    int main ( void ) { return assignment7(); }
```

You don't say what inputs you are giving it, (a test case with inputs and the expected results would be super helpful), but I can point out that `x / (a % 2)` is going to be ***infinity*** when a is 2 or 4 or 6 or ...

Comment: I went ahead and fixed both parts(idk what I was doing in the scanf() lol ). I am still getting at #INF00 error.